# When text input in focus, move cursor to bottom

Tags: html, css, sass

I have forked [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yprmdd) from chris coyer example and I am wanting to make the label move to the top instead of the bottom as his was doing.

In so doing, I simply can't get the cursor/carrot to move to the bottom instead of staying at the top, and so when you type, it overwrites the label and is a mess.  The code to move label (still called `go-bottom` but that doesn't matter)

```
form.go-bottom {
  input {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px; 
  }
  label {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  input:focus {
    padding: 4px 6px 20px 6px;
  }
  input:focus + label {
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: -36px;
  }
}
```

I've tried various padding settings on the input and for some reason none are affecting the cursor position itself - if anyone can help adjust it that would be great. (this is purely css/sass based and don't want any JS or other)

Bonus points for changing the transition animation to go from bottom to top instead of top to bottom :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding more top padding and less bottom padding for the input on focus.

```
input:focus {
    padding: 17px 6px 4px 6px;
}
```

I would play with overall padding too if your going to try this approach, the inputs feel cluttered when 2 lines of copy.

Comment: oh damn that must have been the one thing i didnt try :) thanks and yeh you are right regarding the clutter